# Check user online or offline icons

Tags: java, android

I have chat app and i have fragment and show in it my friends , and currently i think to add online and offline feature next to user name in my friend fragment, I wrote the code and it working without problem , But i need to add icon online or offline next to The Full name of users, In layout i added the icons but i can't control these in code, I want if user online.. online icon set visibilty visible and offline icon set visibilty invisible and i want if user offline.. online icon set invisible and offline icon set visible.. this is my problem just!

Note: The icons is ImageView...

I wrote comment above my problems in fisrt class and in layout xml..

**I have to class the first class(FriendsFragment):**

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {
public static int setOnlineSta;
RecyclerView results_list;
DatabaseReference mUDB,mUDBSec;
FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
FriendsAdapter friendsAdapter;
ArrayList<String> fullNameList,userStatusList, userIdList, profileImageList;
View mMainView;
public FriendsFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String current_uid =  mCurrentUser.getUid();
mUDB = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
.getReference().child("Friends").child(current_ui
d);
mUDB.keepSynced(true);
mUDBSec = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mUDBSec.keepSynced(true);
results_list = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.users_list);
results_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
results_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
results_list.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), 
LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
fullNameList = new ArrayList<>();
userStatusList = new ArrayList<>();
userIdList = new ArrayList<>();
profileImageList = new ArrayList<>();
setAdapter();
return mMainView;
}


private void setAdapter() {
mUDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
final String uid = snapshot.getKey();
DatabaseReference userRef = mUDBSec.child("Users").child(uid);

userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
String uidSec = uid;
userIdList.add(uidSec);
String full_name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
String user_status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class);
String profile_pic = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
fullNameList.add(full_name);
userStatusList.add(user_status);
profileImageList.add(profile_pic);
if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) 
{
// My Problem Here
Boolean userOnline_Check = (Boolean) 
dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue();
if (userOnline_Check == true)
{
}

if (userOnline_Check == false)
{

}
}
friendsAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(getActivity(), fullNameList, 
userStatusList, userIdList, profileImageList);
results_list.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
}

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
}}
```

**Second Class(FriendsAdapter):**

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendsAdapter.FriendViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<String> fullNameList,userStatusList, userIdList,profileImageList;

class FriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
ImageView profileImage;
ImageView active_emo, not_active_emo;
TextView full_name, user_status,user_id;

public FriendViewHolder(View itemView) {
super(itemView);
full_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
user_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_friend);
user_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_id);
profileImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
active_emo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.active_state);
not_active_emo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.not_active_state);
}
}

public FriendsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> fullNameList, 
ArrayList<String> userStatusList, ArrayList<String> userIdList, 
ArrayList<String> profileImageList) {
this.context = context;
this.fullNameList = fullNameList;
this.userStatusList = userStatusList;
this.userIdList = userIdList;
this.profileImageList = profileImageList;
}

@Override
public FriendsAdapter.FriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, 
int viewType) {
View view = 
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, parent, 
false);
return new FriendsAdapter.FriendViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FriendsAdapter.FriendViewHolder holder, 
final int position) {
holder.full_name.setText(fullNameList.get(position));
holder.user_status.setText(userStatusList.get(position));
holder.user_id.setText(userIdList.get(position));
Glide.with(context).load(profileImageList.get(position)).into(holder.profile
Image);

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Open Profile", "Send message"};

final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

builder.setTitle("Select Options");
builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

//Click Event for each item.
if(i == 0){

Intent profileIntent = new Intent(context, UserProfile.class);
profileIntent.putExtra("USER_ID",String.valueOf(userIdList.get(position)));
context.startActivity(profileIntent);

}

if(i == 1){

Intent chatIntent = new Intent(context, Search.class);
chatIntent.putExtra("USER_ID",String.valueOf(userIdList.get(position)));
context.startActivity(chatIntent);

}

}
});

builder.show();

}
});
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fullNameList.size();
}}
```

My Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
android:id="@+id/user_single_image"
android:layout_width="65dp"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:padding="2dp"
android:src="@drawable/profile_default" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="233dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/user_single_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Full name"
android:textColor="@color/bluePrim"
android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/username_friend"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="User Name" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/user_single_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="User Id"
android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>

<-- the icons below !-->

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/active_state"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:src="@drawable/active"
android:visibility="invisible" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/not_active_state"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:src="@drawable/notactive"
android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you..

Comment: I think your job would be a lot easier if you made a User class instead of having each individual attribute in a different list.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

follow this approach
and then I will tell you how toshow online/offline status of user

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: @Dziugas can you show mw example or edit the codes to your idea..

Comment: You can follow the example that SAKhan linked to by using a User class instead of the Movie class.